# How to remove prefix of apex:form from elements?

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, form, dom

I amworking on a Visualforce Project where I need to access elements from a form via jQuery.

The problem is that the elements always get a prefix like j_id0:j_id4: in the ID. Therefore I can't access the form through jQuery.

There is this tag, which helps a little. It's called `prependID`. By default it's set to `true`. When set to `false`, I still get the j_id0.

Here's an example for the code. Maybe someone has an idea.

```
        <apex:form prependId="false" id="Form">
            <table>
                <tr><td><label style="color: white;">Case:</label></td><td><apex:inputHidden id="CaseID" value="{!caseID}"/> /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label style="color: white;">Dude:</label></td><td><apex:inputHidden id="DudeID" value="{!dudeID}" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label style="color: white;">Thing:</label></td><td><apex:inputHidden id="ThingID" value="{!thingID}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td><apex:commandButton action="{!setJoined}" immediate="true" value="Submit"/> </td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery you can use the "ends with" selector for the id:

i.e. `$('[id$=Form]')`

Or you can ensure every apex tag element has an ID which will cause the VF page to not prepend the j_id prefixes to the elements.

Comment: Worked Perfectly! 
Thaks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately targeting Ids within native Visualforce components is a little bit of a pain, but it is doable.

The 'recommended' way is to make use of the `$Component` global variable. Which when used properly will let you get ahold of the full untidy Id that Salesforce gives the DOM elements.

> Use the `$Component` global variable to simplify referencing the DOM ID that is generated for a Visualforce component, and reduce some of the dependency on the overall page structure. To reference a specific Visualforce component’s DOM ID, add a component path specifier to `$Component`, using dot notation to separate each level in the component hierarchy of the page. For example, use `$Component`*.itemId* to reference a component at the same level in the Visualforce component hierarchy, or use `$Component`*.grandparentId.parentId.itemId* to specify a more complete component path.
>
> A `$Component` path specifier is matched against the component hierarchy:
>
> - At the current level of the component hierarchy where $Component is used; and then
> - At each successive higher level in the component hierarchy, until a match is found, or the top-level of the component hierarchy is reached.

This is covered off in a lot more detail in the [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm) documentation.

Comment: I will read it, but as this is just going to be a PoC, I think I will go with the Quick and dirty way. 
Thanks for the Support!

Comment: One thing to note, when the path to the component doesn't match or can't be found, no error is thrown; an empty string is rendered there instead. i.e. `var myID = '{$Component.thingsParent.thingNotFound}';` would render as `var myID = '';` into the page markup where you might have expected `var myID = 'myPage:myForm:myPageBlock:myTable';` or `var myID = ' j_id0:j_id4:j_id5:j_id6';` If a blank string is rendered, check the path to the component or make the path more explicit.